# Mongodb's generated UID contain the word "bad"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Does anyone know what a "_id" generated by MongoDB ( or perhaps a Mongoose save ) means when it contains the word "bad" in the middle.

```
eg: 521b633274bad76823000002
```

I couldn't find an answer on the net or here.

This was happening on "save", but only discovered when I wanted to "update" the document. It would not allow an update.

```
 db.collection.update(...
```

The callback from the attempted 'updated' object was always null and the document was not updated.

Switching my database resolved the issue, so I am confident this is not in code ( and the code is very simple )

Using both mongojs and mongoose on Node.

Many Thanks,

Rob

Comment: correction, it looks just like on the one record. Thanks. Sounds like I am on a red herring. : ))

Comment: Well the fact that update didnt work threw me off, I thought for a sec that maybe a part of the ObjectId class was returning "bad" for its part

Comment: yeah @Sammaye, hate these kind of times where I 'think' I have spotted something that coincides with an error. - can't be me :S up the garden path I go. Thank goodness for folks like you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.

The [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) is a hexadecimal string which can include the characters `0123456789abcdef`. That means that any word which can be written with those 6 letters, like "bad", "beef", "dead", "deaf", "babe" or "cafe" has a certain probability to appear in them (for the exact probability, please consult [our friends](http://math.stackexchange.com)).

In your case, the string "bad" appears in the three bytes which are the machine-ID ("74bad7"), so all ObjectIDs created by the same machine will contain this 6-digit string. How the machine ID is generated depends on the driver, but usually it is created by using the first 6 digits of the MD5 hash of either the hostname or the MAC address. So when you don't want any more "bad" objectID's, experiment with changing those and brute-force them until you get one you like ;)

Your problem with updating your document must have some other reason, but the details you provided don't include a hint what the problem could be.

Comment: Thanks Phillipp, worth asking this question for sharing that information! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It's just a coincidence as any of the hex characters `abcdef` can appear anywhere in an ObjectID value and occasionally group to make fun words like bad, dead, beef, etc.

Comment: Thanks Johnny and earlier comment that has disappeared. 

Yeah, looks like I jumped to that as why updates failing, ie, bad = corrupt or similar.